# Setting the forecolor property of a DataGridViewRow conditionally and receiving inconsistent results

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having some issues with the conditional formatting of a DataGridView and cannot seem to find the problem myself.

The DataGridView is populated with a datasource retrieved from an entityframework DbSet. It represents a bed listing of a hotel and all the clients in the various beds. I am trying to color code the current client listings with the different statuses available in this business. However, I am receiving inconsistent results. The code should color all statuses of a certain string value red, another status green and if the transaction of the client still shows an owing amount then the color should be blue.

I am handling the DataBindingComplete event to affect these changes. The problem would be easier to solve if I wasn't getting any results but the problem is that certain transactions are showing the correct color code and others aren't even though they have the same status id and are inputted into the system in exactly the same way.

The code is as follows:

```
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {

            string statusVal = (string)row.Cells["StatusId"].Value;
            //statusVal = statusVal.Trim();

            int stay = 0;

            if (row.Cells["StayId"].Value != null )
            {
                stay = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var context = new ArcContext())
            {
                Stay st = context.Stays.Include(s => s.Transaction).Where(s => s.StayId == stay).First();

                if (st.Transaction.AmountDue > st.Transaction.AmountPaid)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (statusVal == "HC" ) 
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                    }
                    else if (statusVal == "F") 
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've tried changing the if statement into a switch case and I still get the same issue. I've also tried (and then commented out) trimming the string in case there was an issue with the string value when being retrieved from the right column.

It's quite strange to say the least. I've re-checked the input code and two beds that are input exactly the same with the same status of HC (eg) will have one showing as red correctly but another not showing as red at all.

All help will be much appreciated.

Edit:

I have also tried using the same code with the CellFormatting Event instead but with the same inconsistent results.

Edit two:

I should also add that the datagridview is being dynamically created at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure out the answer to this myself. It's actually quite simple and embarassing!

There should have been a continue; where the return; is in the else section of the first if block. The return obviously brought the foreach loop to an end and so the formatting stopped applying after any null values were encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing kind of thing in CellFormatting not DataBindingComplete.

Comment: Hey Gary, I forgot to mention that I did indeed try the CellFormatting Event first and was having the same problem so tried handling a different event instead.

Comment: Can you show your code for CellFormatting? That is the correct place to start.

Comment: Hey Gary, it's the exact same code but with a different eventhandler. I can edit the question to include it but it would just be a duplicate of the code already there.

Comment: That code would never work in CellFormatting, it gives you the row and column of a specific cell to format. You can't iterate through all the rows and change them. You are also required to set the CellStyle in the event argument.